# Istio ServiceEntry not working (for tcp port 22 (ssh)externally)

Tags: kubernetes, containers, devops, istio

I have a flaskr app I wrote that has two containers.  I'm implementing istio to get used to it.  I'm having an issue though where ServiceEntry's are not allowing TCP port 22 (ssh) traffic from a container external to the mesh.  My ServiceEntry's look like this and overall app looks like this.

```
    *ubuntu@k8s-master:~/applications$ kubectl get serviceentry srx-ssh-service-entry -n home-devices-app -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-02-25T01:29:10Z"
  generation: 1
  name: srx-ssh-service-entry
  namespace: home-devices-app
  resourceVersion: "7848269"
  selfLink: /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/home-devices-app/serviceentries/srx-ssh-service-entry
  uid: c03f2f27-389c-11e9-ad97-000c297d3726
spec:
  addresses:
  - 22.22.22.22/32
  hosts:
  - 22.22.22.22
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    number: 22
    protocol: tcp
  resolution: NONE
ubuntu@k8s-master:~/applications$ kubectl get serviceentry ex-ssh-service-entry -n home-devices-app -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-02-25T01:29:10Z"
  generation: 1
  name: ex-ssh-service-entry
  namespace: home-devices-app
  resourceVersion: "7848270"
  selfLink: /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/home-devices-app/serviceentries/ex-ssh-service-entry
  uid: c040f3d1-389c-11e9-ad97-000c297d3726
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.4.1/32
  hosts:
  - 192.168.4.1
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    number: 22
    protocol: tcp
  resolution: NONE
ubuntu@k8s-master:~/applications$*
```

[jpeg of deployment overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9jWZ.jpg)

Here is some other pieces of info if it helps.  Any help is appreciated!

```
ubuntu@k8s-master:~/applications$ cat home-device*
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: home-devices-app-service
  namespace: home-devices-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: home-devices-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31337
    port: 5000
    name: http
    targetPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: home-devices-deployment
  namespace: home-devices-app
  labels:
    app: home-devices-app
spec:
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: home-devices-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: home-devices-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: home-devices-app
        image: lemon-flaskr-container:2.2
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: home-devices-app-srx-function-service
  namespace: home-devices-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5001
    name: http
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    app: home-devices-app-srx-function

---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: home-devices-srx-function-deployment
  namespace: home-devices-app
  labels:
    app: home-devices-app-srx-function
spec:
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: home-devices-app-srx-function
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: home-devices-app-srx-function
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: lemon-home-dev-srx-function
        image: lemon-home-dev-srx-function:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5001
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: home-devices-app-envoy-gateway
  namespace: home-devices-app
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: "home-devices-app-virtual-service"
  namespace: home-devices-app
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - home-devices-app-envoy-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /guestwifi
    route:
    - destination:
        host: "home-devices-app-service"
        port:
          number: 5000
```